# Tailwind autogenerated css file variables empty

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css, postcss, tailwind-3

I am using tailwind with postcss configuration that generates a CSS file to be used in production with only the needed CSS classes for the app. However, when the CSS file gets generated, I noticed many empty CSS variables that, in my opinion, are not serving any purpose and my IDE is recognizing them as an error. An example of one of these classes is the following:

```
    *, ::before, ::after {
  --tw-translate-x: 0;
  --tw-translate-y: 0;
  --tw-rotate: 0;
  --tw-skew-x: 0;
  --tw-skew-y: 0;
  --tw-scale-x: 1;
  --tw-scale-y: 1;
  --tw-pan-x:  ;
  --tw-pan-y:  ;
  --tw-pinch-zoom:  ;
  --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity;
  --tw-ordinal:  ;
  --tw-slashed-zero:  ;
  --tw-numeric-figure:  ;
  --tw-numeric-spacing:  ;
  --tw-numeric-fraction:  ;
  --tw-ring-inset:  ;
  --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
  --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;
  --tw-ring-color: rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);
  --tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-blur:  ;
  --tw-brightness:  ;
  --tw-contrast:  ;
  --tw-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-invert:  ;
  --tw-saturate:  ;
  --tw-sepia:  ;
  --tw-drop-shadow:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-blur:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-brightness:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-contrast:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-invert:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-opacity:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-saturate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-sepia:  ;
}
```

How can I get rid of those classes if they are not necessary? Most importantly how can I stop Tailwind from auto-generating these classes? Am I doing something wrong?

This is my tailwind.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    colors: {
      "primary-darker": "#45622E",
      "primary-dark": "#5A7B31",
      "primary-med": "#76A340",
      primary: "#96BA57",
      "primary-light": "#F3F9EC",
      white: "#FFFFFF",
      "secondary-dark": "#202020",
      secondary: "#262626",
      "secondary-light": "#373737",
      "active-gray": "#999999",
      "inactive-grey": "#D8D8D8",
      "background-grey": "#F8F8F8",
      "background-light": "#F2F2F2",
      success: "#83C117",
      alert: "#B63A2F",
      current: "currentColor",
    },
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        konnect: "Konnect, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
        "konnect-medium": "Konnect Medium, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
        "konnect-semibold": "Konnect SemiBold, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
        "konnect-light": "Konnect Light, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

and this is the command I use to auto generate file with tailwind:

```
"tailwinds:build": "npx tailwindcss -i src/assets/sass/tailwind.scss -o ./public/output.css --watch"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tailwind uses the empty strings in these variables as placeholders. According to them it's a feature, not a bug. Because they use the variables later and would run into an error, if they were undefined.

Relevant issue on Github: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/7121

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I know see that this is part of the framework utilization. We are using Codacy for detecting issues in our source coed. I guess we will just ignore the generated file for now since my IDE, as well as Codacy, are detecting these empty fields as issues.

Comment: @KevinGarcia if my reply helped you, please mark it as solution. thx

Comment: Still, it sucks. Makes all pages using tailwind invalid according to W3C.

Comment: If Tailwind cared about what the W3C values then it wouldn't exist. It's inline styles all over again.